# git-stash cannot be used without a working tree error

Tags: git

I use git 2.7.2.windows.1. I encounter **"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-stash cannot be used without a working tree."** when I try to use **git-stash** command.

**git worktree list** command output:

```
E:/Git Repositories/test-desktop-client  63bb5ca [master]
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a bare repository? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605884/git-pull-cannot-be-used-without-a-working-tree

Comment: I am not sure my repository is bare but pull-push-merge command working correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863372/git-stash-unable-to-find-work-tree

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ git --work-tree=. stash
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a recent [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) (as in "[managing multiple wroking tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)") and stash, for some reason, does not work, you can use an *additional* worktree as an alternative to stashing:

> You are in the middle of a refactoring session and your boss comes in and demands that you fix something immediately.
>   You might typically use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) to store your changes away temporarily, however, your working tree is in such a state of disarray (with new, moved, and removed files, and other bits and pieces strewn around) that you don’t want to risk disturbing any of it.
>   **Instead, you create a temporary linked working tree to make the emergency fix, remove it when done, and then resume your earlier refactoring session**.

```
$ git worktree add -b emergency-fix ../temp master
$ pushd ../temp
# ... hack hack hack ...
$ git commit -a -m 'emergency fix for boss'
$ popd
$ rm -rf ../temp
$ git worktree prune
```

That being said, git stash should work in a git worktree.
Start by checking if `git config core.bare` is false.